# Append input with jQuery with uniqe id

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the button jQuery append new input inside the div like below:

```
$('#addIndirectCityBtn').click(function () {
    var inputs = $("#additionalCityInputs input").length

    if (inputs <= 3) {
        $('#additionalCityInputs').append('<input type="text" placeholder="Miasto" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" />')
    }
})
```

How I can add uniqe ID to each new input?
Fore example id="new1" for the second one id="new2" and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addIndirectCityBtn').click(function () {
    var inputs = $("#additionalCityInputs input").length

    if (inputs <= 3) {
        var newId = 'newId'+(inputs + 1);
        $('#additionalCityInputs').append('<input id="'+newId+'" type="text" placeholder="Miasto" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" />')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#addIndirectCityBtn').click(function () {
    var inputs = $("#additionalCityInputs input").length

    if (inputs <= 3) {
        $('#additionalCityInputs').append('<input id="new' + ++counter + '" type="text" placeholder="Miasto" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" />')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use an IFFE

```
  (function(){
      var a = 0;
       $('#addIndirectCityBtn').click(function () {
        var inputs = $("#additionalCityInputs input").length

        if (inputs <= 3) {
            $('#additionalCityInputs').append('<input id="new'+ ++a + '" type="text" placeholder="Miasto" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" />')
        }
    })
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some counter variable to achieve this.

```
var i=0;
$('#addIndirectCityBtn').click(function () {
    var inputs = $("#additionalCityInputs input").length;
    i++;
    if (inputs <= 3) {
        $('#additionalCityInputs').append("<input id='new"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Miasto' class='form-control' style='margin-bottom: 5px;' />");
    }
});
```